# Why does the equation $z=2Ae^{k_1x - \omega t}\cos{k_2y}$ describes a travelling wave in $x$-direction and a standing wave in $y$-direction?

Tags: waves

There is an ideal membrane, defined by axes $x \in (-\infty,+\infty)$ and $y \in (0,+\infty)$. The membrane has an homogeneous surface density $\sigma = \frac{dm}{dS}$ and it is streched in every direction by a fixed power: $T=\frac{\Delta F}{\Delta L}$. The side of the membrane that's parallel to axis $x$ is fixed at $y=0$ such as all the points ($ -\infty <x < \infty$ , $y=0$) are immobilised.

Far away from this (immobilized) side of the membrane, a transverse wave is transmitted through it, with angular $\omega$ that it is described by $z=Ae^{i(k_1x -k_2y + \omega t)}$ whereas $k_1=k_2\sqrt3$. After, the wave has reached $y=0$ and in the whole membrane co-exist both the incident and the reflected wave, then we can compute that the motion, of every   point of the membrane

$$z = z_\text{in} + z_\text{refl} \rightarrow \\ z=Ae^{i(k_1x -k_2y + \omega t)}+ Ae^{i(k_1x +k_2y + \omega t)} \rightarrow \\ z=2 Ae^{i(k_1x  -\omega t)}\cos(k_2y).$$

And then there is this sentence: So, there is a transversal wave in direction "x" and a standing wave in direction of "y" axis.

I think that I  get how this equation describes a transversal wave in $x$ direction ( the travelling wave is : $2 Ae^{i(k_1x  -\omega t)}$ (let me know if I am wrong) but how do we know about the standing?

Some extra questions:

- Can we describe what exactly happens in the membrane in each stage? For example before the wave reaches the fixed side of the membrane there is only one wave , the incident. But then we also have a reflected wave described by $k'=(k_1,k_2)$ where the incident can be described by $k=(k_1,-k_2)$. That's right after the incident wave has reached axis $x$. But what happens after? The problem states, that they will co-exist and create a new wave described by $z=2 Ae^{i(k_1x  -\omega t)}\cos(k_2y).$. Is this all that's ever gonna exist from so on in the membrane? The initial wave we created? Or do both the incident and the reflected wave exist , autonomously in the membrane , but somehow since both have been transimtited in every point of the membrane after a while , it's easier to describe the motion of one point of the membrane by a single equation that sums up everything , so we write $z=2 Ae^{i(k_1x  -\omega t)}\cos(k_2y).$?
- Why we say that the incident wave , is a surface wave? I know that : the vector $k=(k_1,-k_2,0)$ but $\vec{k}\vec{r} \neq c$ since $|k|=c$ but $|r|\neq c$  ($c$ stands for "constant")

Comment: In the title you use $\cosh$ but in the body you use $\cos$. Any particular reason?

Comment: You are supposed to be adding the displacement $z$.

Comment: Your final cosine is supposed by have $y$.

Comment: The title has a factor of 2 that isn’t in the body.

Comment: Just a quick remark: I think in the last equation you should have $y$ rather than $x$ in the cosine. Also maybe in the same equation you should use $z(x,y,t)$ rather than $y$ to indicate the wave amplitude

Comment: These mistakes make the question unclear.

Comment: @Gert An editor corrected one cosh to cos but not the other. It wasn’t me,  but I’ll fix it.

Comment: The sign of the $\omega t$ flipped at the end.

Comment: All $\cos$ now...

Comment: you are right I fixed them , I think

Answer (score 1):

For fixed $y$ we clearly get a travelling wave with amplitude $2A\cos(k_2y)$ because of the exponential factor.

For fixed $x$ we get a standing wave because $\cos(k_2y)$ describes the nodes and is the only function of $y$ allowed to change if $x$ is fixed.

Comment: Ι fixed some typinh errors in my post , does your answer change?

Comment: Yes, because cosh(y) is an ever-increasing function so this doesn't represent a standing wave. It should be a cos(y) because $e^{iy} + e^{-iy} = 2 \cos(y)$.

Comment: you are right , I fixed that, but what term exactly describes the standing wave in y, I did not get that

Comment: for a fixed x=xo, we get $2Ae^{ik_1x}=C$ so , $z=Ce^{-i\omega t}cos(k_2y)=C[cos(-\omega t) - isin(\omega t)]cos(k_2y)$

Comment: Like @brucebanner said, for fixed x you get something like $B(t) \cos(k_2y)$ which describes a standing wave with an amplitude changing in time, but it's not travelling because the nodes/zeroes and maxima remain at the same positions in the y-coordinate.